# How can I edit android context menu in a built-in phonebook?

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

So when user browses their phonebook and long-holds on contact it opens standard menu and I want to add extra option there.

Comment: so far what you have tried for that ?

Comment: There are ~1.5 billion Android devices, spanning thousands of device models. These devices will have hundreds of built-in "phonebook" apps, and users can install other ones from places like the Play Store. You are welcome to iterate over that list of phonebook apps, contact the developers for each, and see if they offer some sort of an API to allow third-parties to be injected into their apps' UIs.